# How to start with the number 1 in a for loop?

Tags: python, string, output

I want the first output to be "Enter the burst time of process 1" instead of "process 0". How to i do this?

```
 num = int(input('Enter the number of processes: '))

    for i in range(num):
            b = input('Enter the burst time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
            a = input('Enter the arrival time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
```

Comment: `str(i + 1)` or `range(1, num + 1)`

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For loops work like so:

```
for [variable] in range(start, end, increment)
```

per your example, you would like to start at 1, and end at 5 for example

```
for [variable] in range(1, 5)
```

the values will display

```
1
2
3
4
```

End value always is 1 less because it counts 0, so you want to add +1 to the end if you want the exact number.

Answer (score 1):

Python's range function returns integers starting between 0 and the given number if there is no starting parameter. 
For instance:

```
for i in range(3):
    print (i)
```

returns:

```
0
1
2
```

if you want to alter your code to print the range starting from 1 and inclusive of the given input, you may consider slightly changing the function to this:

```
num = int(input('Enter the number of processes: '))

for i in range(1,num+1):
    b = input('Enter the burst time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
    a = input('Enter the arrival time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
```

If you don't want your range to be inclusive of the given integer you can just do it like this:

```
num = int(input('Enter the number of processes: '))

for i in range(1,num):
    b = input('Enter the burst time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
    a = input('Enter the arrival time of process ' + str(i) + ': ')
```